# ¿Cómo alinear objetos de DOM con CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Como puedo hacer para alinear a la misma altura el texto que aparece marcado en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código HTML:

```
  <div id="banner" class="divBanner row container-fluid col-12">
       <img id="logSudoku"  class="logoInitial col-1" />
       <label class="fontInitial col-12"> Sudoku de Todos </label>
        <ul class="row" style="margin-left:30%">    
             <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="menuStick" class="abrir-cerrar" onclick="MenuStick()" style="color:white;font-size:18px;"> Menu </a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="/Home/Index" id="inicio" style="color:white;font-size:18px;">Inicio</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="/Home/Contact" id="entrar" style="color:white;font-size:18px;">Entrar</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
        </ul>
 </div>
```

código CSS

```
.divBanner {
    background-color: green;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    height: 20vh;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.logoInitial {
    height: 100px;
    width:6vw;
    margin-right: 100%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-top:0%;
}
```

Comment: No deberías usar un `label` para texto normal, por semántica los `label` son para asociar un texto con un campo de formulario. Para lo de alinear veo que usas bootstrap, lo mejor sería que pusieras el texto en una columna y el menú en otra.

Answer (score 1):

Si metes la imagen dentro del "ul" te debería de alinearlos.

```
  <div id="banner" class="divBanner row container-fluid col-12">
    <ul class="row" style="margin-left:30%">
         <li><img id="logSudoku"  class="logoInitial col-1" /><label class="fontInitial col-12"> Sudoku de Todos </label></li> <!--AQUÍ-->
         <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="menuStick" class="abrir-cerrar" onclick="MenuStick()" style="color:white;font-size:18px;"> Menu </a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="/Home/Index" id="inicio" style="color:white;font-size:18px;">Inicio</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="/Home/Contact" id="entrar" style="color:white;font-size:18px;">Entrar</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
    </ul>
```

Comment: de esa forma no lo hace

Answer (score 1):

no me carga la imagen y no puedo ver si quieres alinear algo más que los enlaces del listado pero este se alineará con un simple:

```
li {display: inline-block}
```

en caso de que necesites que alinie todo puedes dividir el contenido div banner en columnas ya que utilizadas boostrap 4 de manera que se coloquen como consideres. ejemplo:

```
<div id="banner" class="divBanner row container-fluid align-items-center">
       <img id="logSudoku" class="logoInitial col-1" />
       <label class="fontInitial col-auto col-md-2"> Sudoku de Todos </label>
        <ul class="col-12 col-md-auto">    
             <li style="list-style:none; display:inline-block"><a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="menuStick" class="abrir-cerrar" onclick="MenuStick()" style="color:white;font-size:18px;"> Menu </a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <li style="list-style:none; display:inline-block"><a href="/Home/Index" id="inicio" style="color:white;font-size:18px;">Inicio</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <li style="list-style:none; display:inline-block"><a href="/Home/Contact" id="entrar" style="color:white;font-size:18px;">Entrar</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
        </ul>
 </div>
```

quiza no he entendido lo que necesitas hacer, no veo la imagen que adjuntas, pero el código que te facilito a mi me funciona perfectamente. Añado una clase de bootstrap al div para mejorarlo un poco. Me da error al adjuntar un pantallazo en que se ve como carga bien.

Comment: de esa forma no lo hace

Comment: Her modificado mi respuesta por si quieres ver lo que te comento, pero en realidad es que el código que te decía a mi me funciona y que quizá es que no entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer al no ver la img que adjuntas. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Prueba encapsulando los elementos y añadiendo "display flex" y "align-items center":

```
<div id="banner" class="divBanner row container-fluid col-12">
  <img id="logSudoku"  class="logoInitial col-1" />
  <div class="fila">
    <label class="fontInitial col-12"> Sudoku de Todos </label>
    <ul class="row" style="margin-left:30%">    
      <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="menuStick" class="abrir-cerrar" onclick="MenuStick()" style="color:white;font-size:18px;"> Menu </a></li>
      <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="/Home/Index" id="inicio" style="color:white;font-size:18px;">Inicio</a></li>
      <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="/Home/Contact" id="entrar" style="color:white;font-size:18px;">Entrar</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.fila {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

el codigo que me funciono es el siguiente:

HTML:

```
<div id="banner" class="divBanner container-fluid">
    <img id="logSudoku"  class="logoInitial"/>
    <ul class="row" style="margin-left:16%">   
        <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="sudoku"  class="listBanner">Sudoku de Todos</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="/Home/Index" id="inicio" class="listBanner">Inicio</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <li style="list-style:none;"><a href="/Home/Contact" id="entrar"  class="listBanner">Entrar</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
    </ul>
</div>
```

codigo css:

```
.divBanner {
    background-color: green;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size:22px;
    width:100%;
}

.logoInitial {
    height: 14vh;
    width:180px;
    margin-right: 100%;
    padding-top:1%;
    margin-left: 19%;
    margin-top:0%;
}
```